# Determine the trend of the market over time use Pandas + python3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
print(df) 



Index Time left     Type          Price
0     1797.0        4.00           0.83
1     1789.0        4.00           0.83
2     1781.0        4.00           0.83
3     1757.0        4.00           0.83
4     1445.0        4.00           0.83
5     1413.0         NaN            NaN
6     1397.0         NaN            NaN
7     1389.0        4.00           0.66
8     1381.0        4.00           0.66
9     349.0         4.00           0.66
10    1325.0        4.00           0.66
11    1317.0        4.00           0.61
12    301.0         4.00           0.62
13    1293.0        4.00           0.65
14    1285.0        4.00           0.56
15    1261.0        4.00           0.56
16    1245.0        4.00           0.56
17    1237.0        4.00           0.57
18    1213.0        4.00           0.51
19    1197.0        4.00           0.52
20    1021.0        3.75           0.86
21    933.0         3.75           0.86
22    813.0         3.75           0.85
23    797.0         3.75           0.85
24    781.0         3.75           0.81
25    525.0         3.75           0.82
26    509.0         3.75           0.82
27    269.0         3.75           0.83
28    181.0         3.75           0.82
29    165.0         3.75           0.82
30    157.0         3.75           0.82
31    37.0          3.75           0.83
```

we can see the `Price` is going down according to `Time left` and `Type`, and value difference

```
df = df.set_index("Type")
a = (df.max(level='Type')["Price"] - df.min(level='Type')["Price"]).sum()

print(a) # value difference: 0.37
```

How does pandas understand whether a market is going up or down over `Time left`(example: `pandas return up=1, down=0`)

My idea:

```
index1 = (["Type"].max & ["Price"].max)

index2 = (["Type"].min & ["Price"].max)

if index1 > index2:
    return 0 (market down)
else:
    return 1( market up)
```

Or is there any more solution, help me convert the idea into code, I have just learn pandas, plz...

Comment: You need to define/explain what 'goes up/down' means mathematically. For example, is it the difference between the last seen price and the first seen price (for each type)? Or is it something else?

Comment: No last seen price and the first seen price, Must be Index of (Max and min (each type)) => compare index

Comment: Pandas doesn't understand anything. You need to use statistics and possibly machine learning. Pandas is a library for loading, saving, querying and manipulating data frames.

Comment: @DannyVarod
you can code: (["Type"]. Max & ["Price"]. Max) => Index 0 and (["Type"].min & ["Price"].max) => Index 20?

Comment: @NguyễnLuận Please see my answer

Comment: @perl Going up or down is based on the index (max and min of each type)

Comment: @NguyễnLuận Yes, that's exactly what is done in my answer. Was there a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find indices of min and max with `idxmin` and `idxmax`, then compare them:

```
# get indices of min and max:
z = df.set_index('Time left').groupby('Type')['Price'].agg(['idxmin', 'idxmax'])

# if index of max < index of min, then it's increasing
# (since it's `Time left`, not `Time`, so it's all reversed)
z = z['idxmax'].lt(z['idxmin']).astype(int).to_frame('is_increasing')
z
```

Output:

```
      is_increasing
Type               
3.75              0
4.00              0
```